# How to not submit a form until after payment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, mongoid

I have a form that I only want to submit to my db if the user has elected to defer pay or they will pay but the charge must be successful first.

So, if the user selects to "pay" in the form then it should go to the charge controller BEFORE it submits the form and get the amount of the charge from the same form. Once the charge is successful then the form should submit.

Here is an example of the flow.

`Submit Form -> Check Attrs :x -> If Attrs X False, Create Record || Elsif Attr True -> Get payment Amount from Attrs: Y, Render Payment View showing Attrs Y as amount due -> Submit Payment Form -> Upon Successful charge -> Create Original Record`

Any ideas on how best to do this? I was thinking a callback to a method in the model to check if the user selected to pay but that still puts the object in the model which creates a chain reaction of events and I don't want those events to start until the user has paid. If the selected that they would pay.

I was thinking maybe javascript or ajax but I am not sure.

Comment: Sounds similar to the way Stripe works

Comment: No need to wait. Let the user fill in all the required information on the assumption that the payment will be accepted. The complete exchange should be one transaction so if anything goes wrong you can rollback. There are too many ways to lose the session and have a incomplete transaction if you dont

Comment: I see what you are saying but this is in mongoid and does not support transaction method.